# Clear all cells from a certain range that starts from the next blank cell in Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some VBA in excel that will clear all cells starting from the next empty cell in Column A (data starts from A2). For example, if A5 is blank then I want A5:P300 to all be cleared (as in all Formula and Data gone). And so on... so if A20 is blank then it deletes everything from A20:P300..

How would I go about writing this? I also need it to refer to the active workbook but a specific worksheet called ("Develop").

Thanks for any help provided.

```
Sub Clear()

Dim x As Worksheet
Dim rng, cell As Range

Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("R&DCosts(2)")

Set rng = x.Range("A2:A340").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

  For Each cell In rng
   If cell.Value = "" Then

      x.Range(cell.Address & ":P350").ClearContents
      End

    End If

  Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service, you will have to come up with some code yourself. What you want to do for a start is is: activate `sheets("Develop")` and create a `for loop` to look for empty cells and delete the rest of the range when it comes up.  Edit your question with the code you have written if you run into trouble.

Comment: @Daghan added my code above - is this correct

Comment: @Daghan My apologies I did write code just cant seem to get my head around it

Comment: @Daisy: Try the code I posted, please. It should do what (I understood) you need, in a very fast way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub clearRange_Bis()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, firstEmpt As Long
  Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("R&DCosts(2)")
  firstEmpt = sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    If firstEmpt > 1000000 Then
        sh.Range("A2:P300").Clear
    Else
        sh.Range("A" & firstEmpt  & ":P300").Clear
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I must confess that when you said "if A5 is blank then I want A5:P300 to all be cleared" I assumed that you made a mistake and your goal was to clear from A5 to P5? Is it my supposition correct? Otherwise, your request looks to not make too much of a sense, in my opinion. But who  knows? If you really need what you requested, the code is  much more simpler, and my code will work based on my assumption...

Comment: No No - I need all of it to clear from A5:P300 is A5 is blank...that is correct...I used your code and got no errors but nothing happened as in nothing cleared

Comment: It clears all the range from A to P on the row having A cell empty. I will post a simpler variant doing what you want...

Comment: @Daisy: Then, try the updated code, please. Do not forget to refresh the page...

Comment: firstEmpt = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1).Row... Error saying No cells were found...My current code copies data in there then I want to call the clear function to clear everything else..there are values in A column for sure

Comment: I found the error. You cannot use "&" in the sheet name, change to R&D to RD :)

Comment: @Daisy: This means that you do not have any empty cell in the range A2:A the last row with value. If this is a possibility (I could not understand that from your question), the code will become even simpler. So, is it true that it is possible to not have empty cells in the A:A column filled with data?

Comment: Very disappointed, thought that would work but it didn't...not sure whats going on here

Comment: @Daisy: Now, it has to work for both situations: empty cells inside the range, or next cell outside it. Please, test it!

Comment: So it starts empty - just the header in A1...Then i run a copy and paste code that copies everything meaning from A2 data gets inputted and now I need the next blank A column to delete everything below including that row...

Comment: The code above shouldnt be ActiveSheet as I have many...shall i change that to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RDCosts(2)")

Comment: Unfortunately, only now you told us how told you like to use such a code. So, the case of empty cell inside the pasted row does not exist?

Comment: @Daisy: Of course, not! I used it only for myself to test the code and (this time) I forgot to change its value... I'm afraid you should learn how to better describe the environment of what you intend to do. I hope the code runs now. But, if the possibility to be an empty cell between A2 and last cell having values does not exist, the code can be simpler. Without looking for EmptyCells inside the range...

Comment: Hi Sorry for late response, the code works now, with a slight issue..it deletes the last field with text. its like its not deleting from the blank but the row above. How would I change that?

Comment: So the range to delete needs to be dynamic depending on the empty row in column  A....There will not be data after the first empty row found...so everything including that empty can be cleared....if that makes more sense

Comment: @Daisy: OK. Adapted the code to work as you need... Do not forget to refresh the page.

Comment: Thank you FaneDuru!! Really appreciate it!! Would have been quicker if I explained properly. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @Daisy: Glad I could help! But I will be more satisfied if you will understand the code logic... :)

Answer (score 1):

### A more simple solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub Clear()

 Dim x As Worksheet
 Dim rng, cell As Range

 Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RDCosts(2)") ' you cannot use "&"

 Set rng = x.Range("A2:A340", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

 For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then

        x.Range(cell.Address & ":P350").ClearContents
        End

    End If

 Next cell

 End Sub
```

Comment: The line: Set rng = x.Range("A2:A340", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) ... I receive the 1004 error message..."Method 'Range' of Object_Worksheet' failed

Comment: That line is from the code you posted, i did not edit, did it work before? Works from here :)

Comment: No unfortunately it didn't work before either, had the same error message

Comment: Try : Set `rng = x.Range("A2:A340")`

Comment: Set rng = x.Range("A2:A340").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) ... Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: Sorry for the bother, not sure why that isnt working

Comment: `Set x = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Develop")`  , do you still have the sheet named like this? Everything works from here, not sure what is going wrong on your end.

Comment: Yep I have that, I have changed the sheet name but ensured both are the same

Comment: Do they have the same capital letters and no spaces at the end of the sheet name ?

Comment: They do indeed, copied it from the actual worksheet name and still getting same error message

Comment: You probably messed up somewhere else then, please edit your question with the correct sheet names so i can check if i get the same error.

Comment: Remove "&" from "R&D" in both the code and sheet name and it works

Comment: I'm so disappointed thought that would work but I am still getting the same error message

Comment: Try opening a new workbook, copy my code without editing it, put some data in a sheet called "RDCosts(2)" with a gap at some point, i really cant see what you are doing wrong :)